# How can I access methods from my Main Activity in my Settings activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mediarecorder

I am currently developing a Voice Recorder app for Android. I am trying to access a few methods in my `MainActivity` from my Settings activity, in order to change some settings for my `MediaRecorder`.

I have the method below, which sets up the Audio Settings for the recording, in my `MainActivity`.

```
// set up all audio settings
private void setAudioSettings() {
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(96000);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.HE_AAC);
}
```

In my Settings activity, [I have a standard preferences screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vMEr.png) that I would like to show options to change the audio codec, sampling rate, etc. of the media recorder in `MainActivity`.

How can I access the `setAudioSettings` method from `MainActivity` here in order to do so?

If you need to see more code or screenshots, please let me know.

Comment: By Only making that method public you can access it, In advance if you want to access it with out creating a Object then you can make that method as static also

public void setAudioSettings() {}

Comment: Since `mediaRecorder` most likely is a field variable (tied to an instance of your activity) making the method static would not work so you'll have to access the activity instance in some way or in turn make the field variable static which has its own issues..

Comment: Use [`startActivityForResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities) and efficient way for such operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make that method as static so you can call without creating the class object

```
public static void yourMethod(){
//Write your code here
}
```

And call your method like this way:

```
MainActivity.yourMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you should not use the functions of your one activity into another activity.

For your case, I would suggest you to have a singleton object or shared preference to store your data of settings screen. Then in onStart of MainActivity, read the singleton object or shared preference and call `#setAudioSettings` method accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

save setting i.e values in shared preferences and then get from preferences in Main Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your method `static` by:

```
  public static void setAudioSettings() {
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(96000);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.HE_AAC);
}
```

But to do that `mediaRecorder` needs to be static also.

Later you can call this method from any activity by:

```
MainActivity.setAudioSettings();
```

You can learn more about `static` keyword for example [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/static-keyword-in-java).

But, I am not sure that use of static method is the best solution for exactly your problem, maybe will be better to set `SharedPreferences` in your `SettingActivity` and later in `onResume()` of your `MainActivity` call `setAudioSettings()` method and get there values from `SharedPreferences`?